# Javascript functions with asp.net button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

Is there a way to add javascript functions to an asp.net button other than the way that is similar to:
(C#)

```
Button link;
link.attributes.add("onmouseover", "functioncall()");
```

Comment: you write it on the client side. use libraries like jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most straight-forward way, quick and dirty...

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" onmouseover="functioncall();"></asp:Button>
```

You should also consider using unobtrusive javascript with the aid of jQuery, by adding custom attributes...

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" data-whatever="value"></asp:Button>
```

Then hook up the function on page load using jQuery...

```
$(function(){
    $('[data-whatever=value]').click(functioncall);
};
```

Comment: From trying your first solution I get a warning that says that onmouseover is not a valid attribute of the element 'Button', should I just leave it alone and move on?

Comment: Yup, just ignore it, the button will indeed be parsed to an HTML button (or submit input) at runtime and it will be correctly render with the onmouseover attribute